# understanding some C code

Tags: c

Quick question. I've never had experience with C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int n, x;
   printf( "How many disks? " );
   scanf( "%d", &n );
   printf("\n");
   for (x=1; x < (1 << n); x++)
      printf( "move from tower %i to tower %i.\n",(x&x-1)%3, ((x|x-1)+1)%3 );
    return 0;
}
```

This is an iterative tower of hanoi. What do things like (x&x-1) and (x|x-1)+1 mean? I figure the % is doing modulus. and %i is a way of printing out integers in C?

Thanks

Comment: You should attempt to learn C before asking questions about it.

Comment: Really, you could have found this online quite easily: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators

Comment: Hi.  This isn't really a good Stack Overflow question; you're asking lots of unrelated questions all in one.  My suggestion would be to get a book on C (or C++), rather than trying to learn the language from scratch here!

Comment: They are [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Comment: Is there a specific problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do things like (x&x-1) and (x|x-1)+1 mean?

`(x&x-1)` is equivalent to `(x & (x-1))`.  `&` is the *bitwise-AND* operator.  Similarly for the second example, where `|` is the *bitwise-OR* operator.

> I figure the % is doing modulus.

[Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

> and %i is a way of printing out integers in C?

[Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Format_placeholders).

Answer (score 4):

1. The `&` operator, like the `*` operator<sup>1</sup> can be used for two different things depending on whether it's used as a *binary* or *unary* operator.

   1. Unary `&` like `&var` takes the address of `var`. This is necessary to pass it to `scanf`.
   2. Binary `&` like `var & var` is a bitwise AND, like item #2.

      - Notice that the spacing doesn't matter. What does matter is if there's operands on both sides of the `&`. So `& var` is still unary `&` and `var &var` is still binary `&`.
2. `(x&x-1)` is doing a bitwise AND with `x` and `x-1`.
3. `(x|x-1)` is doing a bitwise OR with `x` and `x-1`.
4. Yes `%` means modulus.
5. `1 << n` is doing a bitwise shift of 1 to the left `n` digits
6. the `%i` you are seeing as the first argument to `printf` are format symbols to which specify that the next argument is an `int`, so that `printf` can print it properly (because it doesn't know what type it is by itself, so you have to tell it). It has nothing to do with modulus. You can see a very in-depth definition of `printf` here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ (thanks pmg)

   - If `%i` were outside a string, it would be to the left of some other operand, and mean modulus.
   - `%i` in a string doesn't mean anything by itself. It only means something to `printf` because `printf` treats it specially. It searches the string it gets for occurrences of `%format` (where `format` is a format, not the word "format") and does something depending on what format it encounters.

<sup>1</sup> The `*` operator also has two different versions: a unary version and a binary version. The unary version means pointer indirection, and the binary version means multiplication.

Comment: 0. `&` can be used for 2 things; 1. `&var` ... necessary to pass it to `scanf` ... +1 anyways :) Oh and the [POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) is better IMHO for C than the cplusplus.com one.

Comment: you're answering with C++ details and the question is only tagged with C (maybe TMI for the OP). Also you probably meant `scanf` in your reason for using `&` as the `address-of` operator

Comment: @pmg thanks again ha. I saw the "help understanding C/C++" and got stuck in C++ mode. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

- `|` is [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR).
- `&` is [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).
- `<<` is [bitwise shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23).
- `%` is modulus.
- `%i` format string prints an integer.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is a formatted output function, in which `%i` means that the argument is an integer. More information is availible [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) for instance.

The `%` operator is indeed modulus. `&` is bitwise AND, and `|` is bitwise OR.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
for (x=1; x < (1 << n); x++)
```

initializes x to 1 and repeats/iterates until x < (1 left shifted by n).  The left shift basically moves the binary representation of 1 left n binary spaces.  so, 0001 would be 0010 after left shifting 1 - this is similar to multiplying by 2^n.  x is then increased by 1 (x++).  Eventually the increase of x should eventually cause the loop to terminate due to the  x < (1 << n) condition.

```
(x&x-1)%3
```

Says "The remainder of value x (binary and) value x-1 divided by 3.  So, if x is 4, and we're using a 4 bit number (stupid, I know - but it shows the point):

```
0100 &
0011
_______
0000        (binary and means both spots being added are 1, none are here).

= 0
0/3 = 0 R 0 - no remainder here, so print 0.
```

The next statement:

```
(x|x-1)+1)%3
```

Says x (binary or) x-1, with 1 added to that value.  The whole sum there is modded by 3 which is again diving it by 3 and taking the remainder, so if x is 4 again and we're using 4 bit integers:

```
0100 |
0011
_______
0111    (Binary or means either binary number has a 1 in that slot).

= 4 + 2 + 1 = 7 --> 7 mod 3 = 7 / 3 --> 2 R 1, print  remainder of 1 here.
```

printf allows formatted print out of a variable length list of arguments which can be expressions, so here it will print:

```
move from tower 0 to tower 1 <new line>
```

Replacing the %i's with our answers.

Answer (score 1):

`&` and `|` are bitwise operators (respectively, AND and OR operators).

```
  0101 (decimal 5)
& 0011 (decimal 3)
------
= 0001 (decimal 1)


  0101 (decimal 5)
| 0011 (decimal 3)
------
= 0111 (decimal 7)
```

Since the substraction operator's precedence is higher than bitwise operators' precedence :

```
(x&x-1) = (x&(x-1)) 
(x|x-1) = (x|(x-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

More informations : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra